# render author name from text model as foreignkey in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I want to render the author of each post to the template

in my models.py file

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="Email", max_length=250, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    full_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Full name" ,max_length=150, null=True)



    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['full_name']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name

    # For checking permissions.
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    # For which users are able to view the app (everyone is)
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True


class Text(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    document = models.TextField(max_length=None, null=True)
    requirements = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True ,null=True)
    deadline = models.DateField(null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User ,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

NB: i want to render it in the home page so here is my home view

```
def home(request):

    user = request.user
    form = TextForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TextForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            author = User.objects.filter(email=user.email).first()
            obj.author = author
            form.save()
            form = TextForm() 

    texts = Text.objects.all().order_by('-id')



    context = {'form':form,'texts':texts}

    return render(request,'main/home.html' ,context)
```

i want to do something like author_name = Text.author.full_name and then render author_name to the template i'm not sure if this is how to do it but you got what i mean
this might be a bit basic thing but i couldnt figure it out.

Comment: Yes,this is the right way to do it.

Comment: it says 'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'full_name'

Comment: @Tawsif ..................

Comment: oh sorry,i was out.can you please post the error message on your question so we can see??

Comment: in template you can use `{% for text in texts %} author: {{text.author.full_name}}{%endfor%}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add below code in your html template to render author full name.

```
{% for obj in texts %}
  Author Full Name : {{obj.author.full_name}}
{% endfor %}
```